# Application actions based on URL

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect

I am sorry if this question was already asked, but I do not know how to frame it differently - none of my searches found something that answers this.

I am currently using Windows 11 and XAMPP, with Apache 2.4.x and PHP 8.1.x, but the solution I am looking for will eventually run on a Linux (Ubuntu) server using same Apache and PHP versions.

I have two web addresses, say, `https://test1.com` and `https://test2.com` set up on my Windows Host file, that redirects to `http://localhost/testapp` at the moment, which is a local PHP application.

Our goal is to have a session or flag or something set when you enter testapp from either domain, so that I have that information available within the PHP application. Since the redirect happens before we even get to PHP, I suspect the place to do this would be in Apache, and I would need to set and then retrieve the value of a `$_SERVER` variable for the info, or something similar.

**Question:**

How can I achieve this? Can it be achieved?

**Edit:**

From comments from Gerald below, I progressed as follows:

I have the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` captured now before any redirects, and then set it in a session variable, but when I go to `test1.com` in the browser, it obviously goes to `localhost/testapp` as per my instruction, and then the session variable is lost.

I am now in a "different site" to the address I entered as per the browser, so that makes sense (to me anyway).

In my Apache config, I now have:

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so

<IfModule remoteip_module>
    RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
</IfModule>
```

I also have the following in my vhosts, as per the given answer by @HBruijn:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ProxyPass / https://my.loc/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost my.loc:443>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/code/"
    ServerName my.loc:443
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "path\to\server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "path\to\server.key"
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost my.loc:80>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/code/"
    ServerName my.loc
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

It does not appear to do anything, and outputting the `$_SERVER` global variable shows it is not there.

**Secondary question:**

Is there any way I can keep the URL in the browser to not change? Anything I can set in Apache config?

Comment: Like [`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server)?

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` becomes something else. It does not contain `test1.com` or `test2.com`.

Comment: Well, if you actually redirect you will only have the referrer on the first request.

Comment: If you fell for the common misconception that a reverse proxy is a redirect (your actual config would be helpful for clarifications) you only need to configure apache to set the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header.

Comment: I do not have a reverse proxy. I don't even really know what it means. I will look into X-FORWARDED-FOR header. Thanks.

Comment: Having the referred on the first request is an option, as long as I can intercept it early enough. I will investigate that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @GeraldShneider, if you have any ideas for my question now that I have incorporated your above comments, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If your question is answered and you have follow up questions, ask new questions for them. You can link to previous questions for reference if needed.

Comment: I am not sure how it invalidates anything, but noted. Apologies. I am giving more information based on answers given and did what the answer suggested, which is the only official answer - yours were comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a "redirect" on a URL you instruct a site visitor to make a new request with the target URL your webserver provides.

When the request for target URL is made, you can't reliably differ between a request that was made directly for your target URL, of if that request was made by following that redirect.

If the original URL is important and should not be lost; then ***do not redirect***.

You can avoid redirects by either including all domain names that visitors are allowed to use when accessing your web application in the VirtualHost definition with a [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server.example.com
  ServerAlias server server2.example.com server2 localhost *.example.net
  UseCanonicalName Off
  DocumentRoot /path/to/your/content-and-php-code
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

In the above example you can then use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

A different approach would be a reverse proxy on the domains you currently redirect from. Then for every request to example.com your web server makes behind the scenes a second request to `localhost`, which includes an X-FORWARDED-FOR header, that you can use in your backend application.

Something like:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  ServerName localhost
  UseCanonicalName Off
  DocumentRoot /path/to/your/content-and-php-code
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
  # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html 
  # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html
  ProxyPass / http://localhost/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I tried the second option, and got the following added t `$_SERVER`:  `[HTTP_SEC_PURPOSE] => prefetch;prerender` and `[HTTP_PURPOSE] => prefetch` but no `X_FORWARDED_FOR`. Unfortunately, redirect is part of the framework I am using, so I can't NOT redirect. So I have to try option 2.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I can't keep the URL intact using the second option? It keeps redirecting me to localhost, which is not what I thought the reverse proxy did for me. Of course, I could be totally misunderstanding things, but I am not getting your second solution to work.

Comment: ProxyPass and the corresponding ProxyPassReverse (you did add a proxypassreverse directive right?) rewrite HTTP headers, but not HTML/JS and other content. There is probably  something in your application code/configuration that causes the  redirect.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks a lot. I did not have ProxyPassReverse, but after adding that, as well ass  `ProxyRequests On` and `ProxyPreserveHost On` things are working as expected. Thank you so much for your help!